# Replace values in dplyr

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I've got a dataset with some lower detection limit values (values are not consistent) and I want to replace them with half of the detection value.I tried with following r codes but it doesn't work. Can anyone help with this?

```
dat %>% mutate(value=sub("<0.02500","0.0125",value))

Site    value
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.02
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  <0.05100
NR  <0.05100
NR  <0.05100
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  0.02
NR  0.017
NR  0.031
NR  0.025
NR  0.023
NR  0.024
NR  0.023
```

Comment: You may need `dat%>%mutate(value=sub("<0.02500","0.0125",value, fixed = TRUE))`

Comment: I tried, but values replaced with <NA> instead '0.0125'

Comment: Still got same issue

Comment: Can you post `str(dat)` ? Also, try `dat %>% mutate(value=stringr::str_replace(as.character(value), "<0.02500", "0.0125"))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the `value` column is character (as in the Note at the end or if not convert them first) remove the `<` character, convert to numeric and multiply each value by 0.5 or 1.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% 
  mutate(value = as.numeric(sub("<", "", value)) * if_else(grepl("<", value), .5, 1))
```

or using only base R:

```
transform(dat, value = as.numeric(sub("<", "", value)) * ifelse(grepl("<", value), .5, 1))
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Site    value
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  <0.02500
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.02
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  0.01
NR  <0.05100
NR  <0.05100
NR  <0.05100
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  <0.05000
NR  0.02
NR  0.017
NR  0.031
NR  0.025
NR  0.023
NR  0.024
NR  0.023"
dat <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE, as.is = TRUE)
```